# Black Rectangle on my screen

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, tightvnc

I have just installed TightVNC server on my hosted Ubuntu using this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-14-04)

I can't see my xfce4 menu usually on the top left of the screen where there is red arrow as attached below. The black rectangle is draggable on the screen. Can someone help out?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I did not select the default configuration when I first logged in to the box.[image]

To solve the issue , I used this command `rm -r ~/.config/xfce4` and  rebooted the box. When I logged in, I selected **Use default configurations**. For more reference, use this guide [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/224006/resetting-xfce-panels-to-default-settings)